# Prestashop SupplierException when adding new supplier

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Good morning to everybody.

I'm trying to add the 43th supplier on Prestashop back office, but when I click on Save button I get the following error:

```
PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Domain\Supplier\Exception\SupplierException code 0
```

I noticed that when I got the above error, the data is still added to the ps_address table, linking it to id_supplier 0

I also tried editing the information of an existing supplier and I got no errors.

Could anyone help me?